# create list with variables containing classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I am trying to create my own Nbody simulation from scratch. I have created a class (called Body) that contains functions to calculate the forces from the other bodies and move it accordingly. 
I have created another class, called System, that defines the number of bodies, controls the updates of the positions and updates a plot of the system. 
Both classes work fine if I define the number of variables individually like this:

```
d1 = Body(i)
d2 = Body(i)
....
```

and put them in a list `list = [d1,d2, ...]`. i is a string (a name that is used 
The problem with this method is that it is tiresome to do n individual variable definitions and then put them in a list. I have tried to do a loop:

```
self.liste = []
for i in range(n):
            self.liste.append(Body(str(i)))
```

but this returns a list containing Nonetypes (`[None, None, None, ....]`).
It is important to my setup that I end up with a list n different classes (it is okay if they are defined by a variable name). Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: this works for me.

Comment: Try adding print statements after each step. Does the returned (Er..Printed) value match what you expected?

Comment: what do you mean " this returns a list containing Nonetypes " where are you returning anything? do you mean that `self.liste` ends up being a list of `None` values, where exactly does the list of `None`s come from?

Comment: When I print self.liste it returns [None, None, None]

Comment: could you please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), Based on the code you have posted I see no reason this should be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
class Body:
    bodies = []
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n)

for i in range(5):
    Body.bodies.append(Body(i))

for body in Body.bodies:
    print body
    # This also works.
    print body.n
```

Note that if you directly try and print a class, you need a `__str__` (or `__repr__`) method.

Comment: ```__str___``` and/or ```__repr__```.